# realm = plugin>codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I wrote Java custom scanning rules according to instructions on github [sonar-custom-rules-examples/java-custom-rules/](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-rules-examples/tree/master/java-custom-rules). My java custom rules were successfully added to SonarQube, but in the scan Code Engineering Times, the following errors occurs. Can anyone help me in getting solution for the below error.

Any hints to solve the issues are more than welcome!

Thank you!

```
Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven: sonar-maven-plugin: 3.7.0.1746:sonar 
failed: A required class was missing while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar: org.sonar.java.resolve.JavaSymbol$VariableJavaSymbol
[ERROR] realm = plugin>codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] file:/C:/Users/kfzx/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.7.0.1746/sonar-maven-plugin-3.7.0.1746.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] file:/C:/Users/kfzx/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] file:/C:/Users/kfzx/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] file:/C:/Users/kfzx/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.2.1/plexus-utils-3.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] file:/C:/Users/kfzx/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.14.0.2002/sonar/sonar-scanner-2.14.0.2003.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] file:/C:/Users/kfzx/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-2.6.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR} import: Entry[import from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
```

Comment: Which Maven version do you use? Which JDK?

Comment: ibm jdk 1.8, and maven version is 3.5.2 @khmarbaise

Comment: First I would check if you there is an issue with IBM JDK ...please use Oracle JDK or AdoptOpenJDK test check things. .....

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe which components are not compatible?  The sonarqube version is 8.1.0.31237. @khmarbaise

Answer (score 0):

Although it isn't clear why this happens, I circumvented this error in another way. 
That's what code wrote earlier:

```
JavaSymbol.VariableJavaSymbol variableJavaSymbol = (JavaSymbol.VariableJavaSymbol) identifierTree.symbol();
VariableTree variableTree = variableJavaSymbol.declaration();
```

To avoid errors, `JavaSymbol.VariableJavaSymbol` was not used.

```
VariableTree variableTree = (VariableTree) identifierTree.symbol().declaration();
```